# Does nfs persisent volume mount work in a single node kubernetes cluster?If so,how?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs4

I have tried with the volume type 'Hostpath' and it worked fine.Apart from 'HostPath' are there any other volumes supporting single node cluster?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create [PersistentVolume(PV)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) and [PersistentVolumeClaim(PVC)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims) for NFS storage you can follow this [Guideline](https://medium.com/platformer-blog/nfs-persistent-volumes-with-kubernetes-a-case-study-ce1ed6e2c266), therefore I assume that it can also work with default storage class in your single node cluster.

You can also use [NFS Server Provisioner](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner) as a most flexible way to implement NFS Server via Helm Chart.

Furthermore, when decision is to establish connection to the existing and functioning NFS Server, there is possibility to use [NFS-Client Provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client)  Helm Chart.

If you want obtain more information about Volume Types available in Kubernetes, refer to the official [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes).